# Windows Minimised to just the top-bar

Tags: window

I am fairly click-happy and as such, I have no-idea how I did it...

[image: Top Bar]

This is Firefox, and my only option is seemingly to close the window/launch a new one.
Can anybody help?

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the arrow on the left? If that doesn't work, try scrolling on top of the window bar.

Comment: AHA! It was the scrolling that works :) Sliding on the right of my trackpad reduces and expands the window. Thanks for this. If you want to add this as an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Glad it worked :). You can mark hal's answer as correct, if you want (I edited it to add the scrolling method).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most window managers call this 'shading' the window. It is usually done by double-clicking or scrolling on the title bar (you can undo it with the same action), but that depends on the window manager (and I'm not really sure which one you're using). If not, it looks like clicking on the down-arrow on the left will probably do it. For sure, there should be an option in the right-click menu (if you right-click on the title bar) to bring the window back.

Comment: I've clicked the little arrow and selected each of the Options without avail. Double clicking just minimises it.

Comment: Regarding the name, "window shading", note that it is not related to "shadow", but to the device that you put on a window, and can be rolled up, and down to make the window intransparen: a "window shade".